# SX -- Stack Exchange for Emacs!

Tags: app

<sub>[pull requests welcome!](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el)</sub>
[image: stackmode]

SX is a Stack Exchange client for Emacs.  Currently progressing rapidly through its prototyping phase, SX will support the full range of API operations, including network/question browsing and commenting, in addition to certain Emacs superpowers:

- editing source code snippets in their native mode,
- archiving questions for offline reference,
- advanced, instantaneous, and incremental search of cached data, and
- marking questions as read / unread.

### Current Capabilities

#### Reading

- Browsing sites

  - keybound support for different 'tabs'
  - keybound support for changing sites
- Reading/collapsing questions/answers/comments
- Links
- Sending a code block to its own buffer
- ... and more -- unfortunately, we're adding too much functionality too quickly for me to keep track of!  When we hit 1.0, I'll be sure to update this page with a brief overview. :)

#### Writing

- Posting comments
- Asking
- Answering
- Editing

### Screenshots

[image: windmove keybinds are not loaded]
[image: Quote Environment]
[image: SE's OAuth workflow in Emacs]

Comment: I had to Google this to see what crazy bastard has already thought of it and implemented it. Bravo sir

Comment: Very nice.  I was looking for an SO chat client for emacs like circe, but I would really like this as well.

Comment: Written in org-mode inline with the documentation is brilliant. One thing, `stack-api.el` builds to `elisp` and `stack-mode.el` ends up in `emacs-lisp`

Comment: @SteveBuzonas If you would like to provide that as a feature request on the [GitHub page](http://www.github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode), I'm sure we would all be grateful for resources `:)` I do not believe the API provides this functionality yet, but if there a way to bypass the API, I'm all ears!

Comment: @user202930 You specifically should *keep* your comment – it's fantastic XD

Comment: I've taken a stab at your question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SteveBuzonas Chat support is on the radar, but isn't officially planned yet.  There is a way to do it, but it's a little... complicated.  There is much to be done for full SE support before this is considered, though.