# Why is the API giving a different response for preview true/false with POST requests?

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, write-access

#### Update

This expression will evaluate to show the cause.  The only requirement is an emacs with `url`.  As you can see, the result from using `curl` and that from using the `url` package is different.  Fields `upvoted`, `downvoted`, and `body_markdown` are missing from the `url` request.  What is differing between these two requests, and how can I fix the problem?

I recommend instrumenting the function before evaluating it.

Since this issue is bordering off-topic now, I'm going to post [this question on Emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7545/2264).  The underlying issue though still concerns the API.  I believe these two issues have the same cause, but if I should post this as a separate question for tracking purposes, just let me know.

```lisp
(defconst access-token
  "YOUR ACCESS TOKEN")

(defconst key
  "AN API KEY")

(defun tmp:api-bug (use-curl access-token key)
  "Post a test answer to the formatting sandbox."
  (let ((random-body-1 (md5 (current-time-string)))
        (random-body-2 (md5 (md5 (current-time-string))))
        (method "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/3122/answers/add")
        (args
         (mapconcat
          #'identity
          `(,(format "access_token=%s"
                     (replace-regexp-in-string
                      "%" "%%" (url-hexify-string access-token)))
            ,(format "key=%s"
                     (replace-regexp-in-string
                      "%" "%%" (url-hexify-string key)))
            "site=meta"
            "pagesize=100"
            "filter=%%21GoYr1we0U5inG5G7wBg4JBGpbgX%%29C7LDqpy-%%2AbfwPOujOr4SR4W%%29bLNSyYUpQDdTwTj.XChTFB0gfLaAJq0hv"
            "body=this-is-an-answer-test-for-sx.el--%s")
          "&")))

    (if use-curl
        (shell-command-to-string
         (format
          "curl --silent -X POST --data %S %s | gunzip"
          (format args random-body-2)
          method))
      (let ((url-automatic-caching t)
              (url-inhibit-uncompression t)
              (url-request-data (format args random-body-1))
              (url-request-method "post")
              (url-request-extra-headers
               '(("Content-Type" . "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))))
          (with-current-buffer
              (url-retrieve-synchronously method)
            (goto-char (point-min))
            (search-forward "\n\n")
            (delete-region (point-min) (point))
            (buffer-string))))))

(tmp:api-bug t access-token key)
"{\"items\":[{\"owner\":{\"reputation\":160,\"display_name\":\"Sean Allred\"},\"downvoted\":false,\"upvoted\":false,\"score\":0,\"last_activity_date\":1421684370,\"creation_date\":1421684370,\"answer_id\":247295,\"share_link\":\"http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247295/188148\",\"body_markdown\":\"this-is-an-answer-test-for-sx.el--e3eeb6228ed9c2c58e5385b73493f0f0\",\"link\":\"http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122//247295#247295\"}],\"has_more\":false,\"quota_max\":10000,\"quota_remaining\":9979,\"page\":1,\"page_size\":100,\"total\":1}"

(tmp:api-bug nil access-token key)
"{\"items\":[{\"owner\":{\"reputation\":160,\"display_name\":\"Sean Allred\"},\"score\":0,\"last_activity_date\":1421684555,\"creation_date\":1421684555,\"answer_id\":247297,\"share_link\":\"http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247297/188148\",\"link\":\"http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122//247297#247297\"}],\"has_more\":false,\"quota_max\":10000,\"quota_remaining\":9977,\"page\":1,\"page_size\":100,\"total\":1}"
```

---

When upvoting an answer via the API, `preview=true` gives the correct new `score` value but `preview=false` does not.
When the following expressions are evaluated, we receive different responses.

```lisp
(sx-method-call "answers"
  :id 7192
  :submethod "upvote"
  :auth 'warn
  :url-method 'post
  :keywords (list (cons 'preview 'true))             ;; NOTE
  :site "emacs")

=>
[((question_id . 7189)
  (answer_id . 7192)
  (creation_date . 1420761994)
  (last_edit_date . 1420762419)
  (last_activity_date . 1420762419)
  (score . 4)
  (is_accepted . t)
  (owner
   (link . "https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew")
   (display_name . "Drew")
   (profile_image . "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/32a8e553d85d193ee5ae1533ce6ec158?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1")
   (user_type . "registered")
   (user_id . 105)
   (reputation . 6689)))]
```

versus

```lisp
(sx-method-call "answers"
  :id 7192
  :submethod "upvote"
  :auth 'warn
  :url-method 'post
  :keywords (list (cons 'preview 'false))            ;; NOTE
  :site "emacs")

=>
[((question_id . 7189)
  (answer_id . 7192)
  (creation_date . 1420761994)
  (last_edit_date . 1420762419)
  (last_activity_date . 1420762419)
  (score . 3)
  (is_accepted . t)
  (owner
   (link . "https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew")
   (display_name . "Drew")
   (profile_image . "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/32a8e553d85d193ee5ae1533ce6ec158?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1")
   (user_type . "registered")
   (user_id . 105)
   (reputation . 6689)))]
```

Note the difference:

- when `preview=true`, `.score=4`
- when `preview=false`, `.score=3`

However, the POST does succeed; `.score` is updated when you re-retrieve the answer:

```lisp
(sx-method-call "answers"
  :id 7192
  :site "emacs")

=>
[((question_id . 7189)
  (answer_id . 7192)
  (creation_date . 1420761994)
  (last_edit_date . 1420762419)
  (last_activity_date . 1420762419)
  (score . 4)
  (is_accepted . t)
  (owner
   (link . "https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew")
   (display_name . "Drew")
   (profile_image . "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/32a8e553d85d193ee5ae1533ce6ec158?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1")
   (user_type . "registered")
   (user_id . 105)
   (reputation . 6699)))]
```

Note that to reproduce the issue with the Elisp examples provided, you must `sx-authenticate` first.

---

I cannot figure out how to correctly `POST` to the API with curl, so feel free to edit this Q to use curl if you know how.  As it stands, clone [SX -- Stack Exchange for Emacs!](https://stackapps.com/q/3950/11299) (or install `M-x package-install RET sx RET` from MELPA) and require `sx-load`.

<sub>Cross-reference [`vermiculus/sx.el#223`](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/pull/223), [Emacs.SE question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7545/2264)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, the problem was here: `(url-request-method "post")`.

Changing that to `(url-request-method "POST")` fixes everything.